# Is the weird transition after the fight between Ichigo and Grimmjow deliberate?

Tags: bleach

I recently got to the episode in the anime where Ichigo fought with Grimmjow in Hueco Mundo after Inoue healed them both.

However, even though the episode ends at the scene where it looked like Ichigo was about to beat Grimmjow, in the next episode, they were back in "the real world" and the events in Hueco Mundo haven't been mentioned for a couple of episodes now.

Is it just me or is this a weird transition in the storyline? Or is there a higher purpose in such transition and it will somehow make sense later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At that point in the anime they reached the manga storyline so they had to put in several fillers. http://www.animefillerlist.com/shows/bleach here is the complete list of fillers so you can skip them and just go back to the storyline.

Comment: alright that's what I was thinking it was. but it seems weird that it's such a hard transition. Like I'm used to fillers that have a transition that makes sense so atleast you know where it comes from and there is a trigger to make them fit within the storyline. This one jus left me like did I skip a bunchload of episodes?

Comment: I had the same feeling when I got to that part. And it happens twice. Now you can just skip it but then I had to wait for half a year for it to continue. And for the weird transition part, can you come up with a storyline that fits in that part that also allows you to continue with the original story.

Comment: I'm at that point with naruto now. recent episodes are all fillers so it's waiting until they get back to the story line. But for example in naruto they make sure that in the last episode before the fillers someone is talking about it so it makes the fillers look like a flashback. So in a way it makes sense cause it originated from the original story. If that makes sense? lol

Comment: I get what you mean. But at least with Bleach they try to make a nice story happen. And with Naruto I got really annoyed with all the stupid little stories.

Comment: I agree with that, the setup for both anime are completely different ofcourse. But since this is the 3rd anime I'm watching (after dragonball and naruto) I got confused.

Comment: I can understand. If you want to watch an awesome anime with almost no fillers I recommend One Piece.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22086/discussion-between-hyouka-and-nosixties).